# Python Multiple linear regression can't plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression, valueerror

I'm trying to run multiple linear regression but i'm having trouble with plotting my results. I'm trying to plot my 3D plot my i get this output `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (4,) and requested shape (34,)`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 1], Y)
ax.plot(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 1], y_pred, color='red')

ax.set_xlabel('Annual Income (k$)')
ax.set_ylabel('Age')
ax.set_zlabel('Spending Score')
plt.show()
```

Edited:
[image]

Edit 2:
[image]

Comment: `ax.plot(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 1], y_pred, color='red')` you need to use `Y`, not `y_pred`. the shapes of both don't match

Comment: After doing so in my plot my line jumps from one point to another. Is this normal? Edited my post for resulting plot

Comment: @NicolasGervais what if OP is trying to plot both the predictions and the original values?

Comment: @M-Wi this is something that i wanted to do as well after figuring out how to plot my results in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot command should be:

```
ax.plot(X_test.iloc[:, 0], X_test.iloc[:, 1], y_pred, color='red')
```

because `y_pred` contains y values only for the subset `X_test`, not the entire input `X`.

Plotting with connected lines (`ax.plot`) doesn't make sense, because the input data is probably not ordered in a meaningful way and the test set is definitely not ordered even if the input data was ordered.

I would plot it like this:

[image]

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# generate some data as an example.
np.random.seed(1)
n = 20
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(n, 2)), columns=['foo', 'bar'])
Y = X['foo'] + 2*X['bar'] + np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=n)

X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X['foo'], X['bar'], Y, label='data')

for x0, x1, yt, yp in zip(X_test['foo'], X_test['bar'], y_test, y_pred):
    ax.plot([x0, x0], [x1, x1], [yt, yp], color='red')

ax.scatter(X_test['foo'], X_test['bar'], y_pred, color='red', marker='s', label='prediction') 

ax.set_xlabel('X0')
ax.set_ylabel('X1')
ax.set_zlabel('y')
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

There are other ways to do visualization. You could use `np.meshgrid` to generate `X` values on a grid and get `y` values from your predictor and plot it using `plot_wireframe` and plot both the train and test data using vertical lines to indicate their vertical distance from the wireframe. It depends on the data what makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When i make the changes you suggested i get this plot (i have edited my post). Again is this normal? Also my X and Y are like this: ```Y = df0['Spending Score (1-100)']
X = df0[[ 'Annual Income (k$)','Age']]``` How should i go about changing the X[0], X[1] etc. that you have suggested for comparing predicted data with actual data?

Comment: I updated the answer. Next time you ask a question, please include input data as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! One question though, why don't all the data points on the plot have their corresponding 'Prediction'?  Just like the plot you made in your answer, there are only 3-4 'Predictions' made

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets